# Value assigned to object wrapped in an observe expr gives me different values when in or out an IF

Tags: r, shiny

I was doing some tests with `observe` and `reactive` expressions when I just built an expression that gives me two different values for the same object, inside and outside an `if`. Little example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  a <- 1
  b <- 2

  observe({
    if(a != b) {
      print(paste0("inside ", a))
      a <- b
    }

    print(paste0("outside ", a))
    invalidateLater(1000)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ironically, at least for me, the object 'a' outside the if receives the value assigned inside, but the own 'a' from inside can't "see" the update.

Could anyone explain me why does that happen and how could I make a conditional test too look if a value has changed, like `reactivePoll`, but using it just to update widgets instead of getting a value?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to show where. The value of `a` at the first print is 1. Then you change the value to the value of `b` which is 2. `if` statements don't create their own scope so you are changing the observe block level value of `a`, not the server level value of `a`. If you need up update with side effects, you should be using `reactiveValues()` rather than simple function level variables. But it's still not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. But it shouldn't be `if` related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reactiveVal` if you want to build a reactive value. See `?reactiveVal` for more details. Try this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Here we build the reactive values
  #Both a and b are functions. 
  #Calling them with no argument retrieves the value
  #You set the value if you call them with an argument
  a <- reactiveVal(1)
  b <- reactiveVal(2)

  observe({
    if(a() != b()) {
      print(paste0("inside ", a()))
      #here we set the value of a() the same as b()
      a(b())
    }

    print(paste0("outside ", a()))
    invalidateLater(1000)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see, I guess. Was totally misunderstanding reactivity concepts, but I think I'm getting them now..